# In React-Hooks UseRef i cant get the new state value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, react-ref

I am trying useref with react-hooks but  when i call the setAccountVal method , although the state of child changes when i alert the value it is still "Ege". Do you have any idea about this case ?

```
    import React, { useState, useRef, useImperativeHandle, useEffect, forwardRef } from "react";
interface A {
    name?: string;
}

const Child = forwardRef((props: A, ref) => {
    const [acc, setAcc] = useState("Ege");
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        getAlert(value: string) {
            alert("getAlert from Child===>" + value);
        },

        setAccountVal(val: string) {
            setAcc(val);

        },
        acc
    }));

    useEffect(
        () => {
            debugger;
            setAcc(props.name || "dummy");
            console.log(acc + " --");
        },
        [props.name]
    );

const changeState = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
    setAcc(e.currentTarget.value);
}


    return <input onChange={changeState}></input>;
})
function App() {
    let [name, setName] = useState("Nate");

    let nameRef = useRef<any>(null);

    const submitButton = () => {
        debugger;
        const comp = nameRef.current;
        comp.setAccountVal("Mahmut");
        comp.getAlert(comp.acc);
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <p>{name}</p>
            <div>
                <button type="button" onClick={submitButton}>
                    Submit
        </button>
                <Child ref={nameRef} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

When i call a normal method , i can see what i want. But the problem is that i can see new state value on acc state but when i take it from parent it is displaying the old  ( actually the initial state val ("Ege")) state value.

> Edit : Actually what i want to do is below

```
//Child component with forwardRef
const [account, setAccount] = useState("defaultAccount");
const [branch, setBranch] = useState("defaultBranch");
const [person, setPerson] = useState("defaultPerson");

useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    selectedAccount: account,
    selectedBranch: branch,
    selectedPerson: person
}));


//Parent component
const childComponentRef = useRef(null);
//Is it possible to change child component's state? Is it allowed?
childComponentRef.current.selectedAccount = "new account";
childComponentRef.current.selectedBranch = "new branch";
childComponentRef.current.selectedPerson = "new person";

alert(childComponentRef.current.selectedAccount);
alert(childComponentRef.current.selectedBranch);
alert(childComponentRef.current.selectedPerson);

//We can change these variables but child component does not rerender with new values.
```

> Ok! I've found the solution. When i use the ref variables with getter setter now i can set also get the current values with useRef!!

```
//Child component with forwardRef
const [account, setAccount] = useState("defaultAccount");
const [branch, setBranch] = useState("defaultBranch");
const [person, setPerson] = useState("defaultPerson");

useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    **get account(){
     return account;
    },
    set account(val : string){
    setAccount(val);
    },**
    selectedBranch: branch,
    selectedPerson: person
}));


//Parent component
const childComponentRef = useRef(null);
//Is it possible to change child component's state? Is it allowed?
childComponentRef.current.selectedAccount = "new account";
childComponentRef.current.selectedBranch = "new branch";
childComponentRef.current.selectedPerson = "new person";

alert(childComponentRef.current.selectedAccount);
alert(childComponentRef.current.selectedBranch);
alert(childComponentRef.current.selectedPerson);

//We can change these variables but child component does not rerender with new values
```

**Detailed Demo :**

[image: Edit React-Ref with Hooks]
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you're using useImperativeHandle without setting any inputs to it, so the functions never get updated. Just add acc as an input, and it will work:

```
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
  getAlert(value: string) {
    alert("getAlert from Child===>" + value);
  },

  setAccountVal(val: string) {
    setAcc(val);

  },
  acc
}), [acc]);
```

Comment: hey  @anxo  thanks!!, what about to reach directly to "acc". How can i set its value ? Because i can get its value but when i set it doesnt change.

Comment: It depends on the specific case, but my first choice would be to have the state on the parent instead of the child, and pass it down as props (including a setter, if needed), removing the need for useImperativeHandle. If that's not an option, I'd go with refs: they are mutable, allowing all methods to access the current value without propagation problems. Feel free to make a new question with the specifics if you need more tailored advice.

Comment: After a quick look, I'd go with having the state on the parent. React is based on the concept of unidirectional data flow, so the state should be on the common ancestor to all the bits that need it, and it gets passed down. 
See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down .
If the child needs to change it, just have it receive a prop with a function from the parent.

Comment: thank you very much for your helps. But actually i need to reach directly to the ref's state. does useImperativeHandle support this or should i use directly ref without useImperativeHandle ? And i dont want to make available all component contents. I need kinda useImperativeHandle that i can use with variables directly